# Square Bracket on MYSQL Column Name Throwing an Error on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a new mysql table based on a third party database. The third party database has table columns cant be changed, we must use them. However, these columns have numerous uses of the dash (-) in the column names. No problem I thought. These column names can be wrapped in square brackets when we create the table. However when you run an mysql query (eg create table) using the phpMyAdmin tool it throws an error for the use of square brackets. Cannot remove the brackets though because that then leaves the column names with the "-" throwing another error.

Just wondered if anyone has experienced this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: where did you get the info that _"column names can be wrapped in square brackets when we create the table"_ ?

Comment: MySQL uses graves / backticks for [identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: Thank you all. I think I am missing the distinction between backticks for mysql and square brackets which are used by the database provider who is using something other than mysql. The source of the square bracket info was the database provider.

Comment: SQL Server / Transact-SQL uses square brackets

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using backticks (`).
Wrap the name in backticks as MySQL uses backticks for delimiters.

Like so,

```
CREATE TABLE yourTableGG (
    `col-has-dashes` INT,
    `col-with-dashes` VARCHAR(255)
);
```